# How to save multiple elements at index for multiple arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm establishing arrays like this....

```
var vidRankArray = [String]()
var vidIdArray = [String]()
var vidTitleArray = [String]()
var vidDescriptionArray = [String]()
var vidImageArray = [String]()
```

returning Parse info and inserting info like this......

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
        query.whereKey("userObjectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (vid:Array?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if vid != nil
            {

                for items in vid!
                {
                    var i:Int
                    i = 0
                    if items["vid1"] != nil
                    {
                        if let myfav1 = items["vid1"] as? NSArray
                        {
                            let id = myfav1[0] as! String
                            let rank = myfav1[1] as! String
                            let title = myfav1[2] as! String
                            let description = myfav1[3] as! String
                            let image = myfav1[4] as! String
                            self.vidRankArray.insert(rank, atIndex: i)
                            self.vidIdArray.insert(id, atIndex: i)
                            self.vidTitleArray.insert(title, atIndex: i)
                            self.vidDescriptionArray.insert(description, atIndex: i)
                            self.vidImageArray.insert(image, atIndex: i)
                        }
                    }
                    if items["vid2"] != nil
                    {
                        if let myfav2 = items["vid2"] as? NSArray
                        {
                            let id = myfav2[0] as! String
                            let rank = myfav2[1] as! String
                            let title = myfav2[2] as! String
                            let description = myfav2[3] as! String
                            let image = myfav2[4] as! String
                            self.vidRankArray.insert(rank, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidIdArray.insert(id, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidTitleArray.insert(title, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidDescriptionArray.insert(description, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidImageArray.insert(image, atIndex: ++i)
                        }
                    }
                    if items["vid3"] != nil
                    {
                        if let myfav3 = items["vid3"] as? NSArray
                        {
                            let id = myfav3[0] as! String
                            let rank = myfav3[1] as! String
                            let title = myfav3[2] as! String
                            let description = myfav3[3] as! String
                            let image = myfav3[4] as! String
                            self.vidRankArray.insert(rank, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidIdArray.insert(id, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidTitleArray.insert(title, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidDescriptionArray.insert(description, atIndex: ++i)
                            self.vidImageArray.insert(image, atIndex: ++i)

                        }
                    }
```

I'm trying to insert each element from each vid in their respective arrays in order.  I've got if item != nil statements so that if there isn't a particular item it can be skipped over.  I'm having trouble doing this.  It either throws an array out of index error or index out of range.  Confusing because it worked perfect when all my items where appended.  Please give me any ideas.

****** UPDATE  *******
I added this...

```
for items in vid!
                {
                    for var i=0; i<vid!.count; ++i
                    {
                    if items["vid1"] != nil
```

and now my console prints out this....

```
["2", "2", "1", "1"]
["3fy4cqWMhyI", "3fy4cqWMhyI", "TI0DGvqKZTI", "TI0DGvqKZTI"]
["Wonder Girls (원더걸스) - Be My Baby", "Wonder Girls (원더걸스) - Be My Baby", "EXO-K_중독(Overdose)_Music Video", "EXO-K_중독(Overdose)_Music Video"]
["Wonder Girls\' 2nd Album Title Song \"Be My Baby\" Copyrightⓒ 2011. JYP Entertainment. All Rights Reserved ▣ Wonder Girls 2nd Album Site ...", "Wonder Girls\' 2nd Album Title Song \"Be My Baby\" Copyrightⓒ 2011. JYP Entertainment. All Rights Reserved ▣ Wonder Girls 2nd Album Site ...", "The music video of EXO\'s \'Overdose\' is released! EXO is back with a new mini album with a more powerful performance that will make you \'overdose\' on their ...", "The music video of EXO\'s \'Overdose\' is released! EXO is back with a new mini album with a more powerful performance that will make you \'overdose\' on their ..."]
["https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3fy4cqWMhyI/default.jpg", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3fy4cqWMhyI/default.jpg", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TI0DGvqKZTI/default.jpg", "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/TI0DGvqKZTI/default.jpg"]
```

Feels like I'm close. Any Ideas why it's giving me 2 of each out of order?

******* UPDATE ********

I got it to work sort of.  I deleted the var i = 0 statements and made the insertAtIndex's explicit.  It worked fine when I definitely had vid1 and vid2.  I did vid4 and it fell out of range because it didn't see vid3 or index 2.  How can I get it to skip and simply add information for the ones saved i.e. what I was trying to accomplish using var i=0; i

Comment: Consider to use a struct oder custom class mit properties `rank`, `id`, `title`, `description` and `image` to hold the properties of one item respectively.

Comment: Please see 2nd update.  I sort of got it to work. How do I skip through each item and only add elements that exist?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `var i`, every `insert(variable, atIndex: index)` and replace it with `append(variable)`. You have really messy code with integers, sometimes you increment i, sometimes you don't. With `append()`, you are sure it will append your item to the array so it will be last and the error with range won't show up.